How to print user input bold using Font class
Here is a snippet of my program asking users to enter their ships' coordinates where I want the user input to be printed Bold.
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class WorkArea{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
    System.out.println("\\nPLAYER "+(j+1)+", ENTER YOUR SHIPS' COORDINATES.");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter ship "+(i+1)+" location:");
        String inp = obj.nextLine();
        String[] arrOfStr = inp.split(" ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1]);
    }
    }
    }
    }

For that I did  import Font class and created object to implement that class like the following,
import java.awt.Font;
Font f=new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18);e

right after that, how can i set the scanner object i.e obj into BOLD using this awt class  and I want the coordinates to be printed BOLD on the console using Font object f. Do I need to create a static method to make the user input bold like the following or can i directly set the object into Bold.
public int setFont(Font f, Scanner obj) {
}

I have tried importing Font class and created object for the font class like the following,
 import java.awt.Font;
    Font f=new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18);

    System.out.println("Enter ship "+(i+1)+" location:");
    obj.setFont(f);
    String inp = obj.nextLine();
    String[] arrOfStr = inp.split(" ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr\[0\]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr\[1\]);
    }

    public Font getFont(Scanner obj){

    }


Expecting users input to be BOLD on the console and need clarification on how to define getFont() method or setFont() to make inputs BOLD.

search Java, Terminal ,  ANSI escape codes

Classes in package java.awt are for use in Java GUI applications and not for console applications.

WorkArea.java
Keywords: Terminal , ANSI escape codes
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WorkArea{
    public static final String GREEN_BOLD = "\033[1;32m";  // GREEN
    public static final String RED_BOLD = "\033[1;31m";    // RED
    public static final String BLUE_UNDERLINED = "\033[4;34m";   // BLUE
    public static final String YELLOW_BACKGROUND = "\033[43m"; // YELLOW
    public static final String RESET = "\033[0m";  // Text Reset
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            System.out.println(YELLOW_BACKGROUND  + GREEN_BOLD+"PLAYER "+(j+1)+", ENTER YOUR SHIPS' COORDINATES."+RESET);
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                System.out.println(BLUE_UNDERLINED+"Enter ship "+(i+1)+" location:"+RESET);
                String inp = obj.nextLine();
                String[] arrOfStr = inp.split(" ");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}


Set Background color and bold , at end , RESET.
System.out.println(YELLOW_BACKGROUND  + GREEN_BOLD+"PLAYER "+(j+1)+", ENTER YOUR SHIPS' COORDINATES."+RESET);

Set underlined , at end , RESET
System.out.println(BLUE_UNDERLINED+"Enter ship "+(i+1)+" location:"+RESET);

Linux

Will not work on older Windows:

Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation
10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763

Works on "newer versions" of Windows

Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise Evaluation
10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621

Windows wt (Windows Terminal)

Windows powershell

Windows cmd


Does this work in Windows (without Cygwin or WSL)?

@VGR It can be executed and will work in the following environments on "newer versions" of Windows  (without Cygwin or WSL)  (1)  wt  (Windows Terminal) , (2)  powershell,  (3) cmd  (4) Update Picture.

A link to an explanation of the ANSI codes would make this a better answer.
